# Tomcat user instance not working - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat7

**I installed tomcat7-user and it is not working. Please find below what I did.
I did a system wide installation first not knowing there is a much user specific instance.

```
apt-get install tomcat7
```

It installed successfully, but since I wanted user instance I removed it**

```
apt-get remove tomcat7
```

**Then installed tomcat7 user instance**

```
apt-get tomcat7-user
```

**It shows installed.**

**I created an instance**

```
tomcat6-instance-create mydev-web
```

**Now I can see the folder mydev-web created inside my home**

```
~/mydev-web$ ls
bin  conf  logs  temp  webapps  work

~/mydev-web/webapps$ ls
index.html
```

**I startup tomcat. I could see unable to bind port as already used error. So I made the port 8082**

```
<Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

**I start tomcat**

```
~/mydev-web/bin$ ./startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/adarsh/mydev-web
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/adarsh/mydev-web/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started

~/mydev-web/bin$ ps -a
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 5075 pts/0    00:00:02 java
 5104 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

At browser i give url

```
http://localhost:8082/index.html.
```

**Can I expect this page to showup ?**

**When I try to shutdown I see what looks like error messages.**

```
:~/mydev-web/bin$ ./shutdown.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/adarsh/mydev-web
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/adarsh/mydev-web/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Apr 19, 2013 11:38:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 19, 2013 11:38:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 19, 2013 11:38:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 19, 2013 11:38:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 19, 2013 11:38:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 19, 2013 11:38:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Tomcat stopped
```

Please guide me.. my final target is to try some jsp

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remove the directories listed in `server.loader` and `shared.loader`. The deb package does not create the directories `/var/lib/tomcat7/*`.

Comment: Could you explain where these files are?